# Why use an extra set of parenthesis when using PHP boolean test in an IF()?

Tags: php, boolean

I'm sorry the title of this question is odd. I couldn't find a good way to word it!

The idea is simple, sometimes you see PHP tests this way:

```
if (!a_function("something")) { }
```

Here you can think of it as "if not true". I sometimes see the exact same thing but with extra parenz:

```
if (!(a_function("something"))) { }
```

Why does it require the extra parenz after the bang? Don't they both essentially mean `if (!true)`?

For extra bonus, what are the reasons for the two styles (does this have a name?) and maybe give examples of how they would give alternate results if not used correctly.

---

update:

Here is an example in a PHP script I'm using, the author is testing environment variables and seems to use the styles interchangeably:

```
if (!(extension_loaded("iconv"))) { ... }
if (!(extension_loaded("xml"))) { ... }
if (!function_exists("json_encode")) { ... }
if (!ini_get("short_open_tag")) { ... }
```

I know you can't answer for the programmer here, but why would they be alternating the use of extra parenz when these small functions are right next to each other?
I happen to know that, for example, the return value of ini_get is just the number 1, and the return value of the extension_loaded functions may also just be the number 1, so it seems like there would be no difference. I'm not 100% sure there isn't some other trick to this than simple preference or order of operation.

update 2:

I understand parenz can be used for either clarity, or order of operations, but I'm not convinced it is only personal preference beyond that.
In my example above, everything depends on what is returned by the functions that are being tested.

It's my understanding that by wrapping a statement in parenz, PHP will force it into a bool. But when it's not in parenz, could there be a return value that breaks the code without using the parenz around it to force a bool?

If people say, in my example code above, that there is nothing but personal preference going on, then I'll just have to accept that, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

the parenthesizes are used in case if there are more than 1 logical operator with different precedence, to indicate that "!" operator must be applied after all other operators have been processed. For example:

```
if(!($var1 < $var2))
```

First will be checked if $var1 is less than $var2, and after that will be checked if the result is false.

If use that:

```
if(!$var1 < $var2)
```

then firstly will be checked if $var1 is false and the result will be compared to $var2, that simply do not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required. It's a matter of personal preference. Sometimes you like to have extra parens to be EXTRA certain of how the expression will be evaluated.

```
 if(a or b and c)
```

is confusing.

```
 if ((a or b) and c)
```

is much more clear.

```
 if(a or (b and c))
```

is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

They both work, but some people might have different opinions on which one is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !(should_return_trueA() && should_return_trueB())) {
    // at least one have returned false
}
```

esentially is the same as:

```
if( !should_return_trueA() || !should_return_trueB() ) {
    // at least one have returned false
}
```

It's, in my case, a practice to avoid mistaken/ommited exclamation marks. Useful, when building more complex conditions and looking for all-false or all-true result.

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are not required in the given case, but they can be if, for example, you also assign a variable at the same time :

```
if (($myVar = myFunc()) !== false) {
    // Doing something with $myVar, ONLY if $var is not false
}
```

While, in the following case, it will change the logic

```
if ($myVar = myFunc() !== false) {
    // Here $myVar = true or false instead of the wanted value
}
```